# DBMS table not found when adding geography to SQL view

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql, esri-geodatabase

I'm pretty amateur at SQL but I have an issue that I assume has a simple solution that I'm not getting. I have a SQL view that generates a table in a geodatabase. I want to take the Lat/Long from one of the tables referenced in the view to turn it into a point feature. I've done this with other (admittedly simpler) SQL views and had success so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the view I have:

```
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT [Call].Call.CallID AS CFSID,
    [Call].Call.CallNumber AS CFSNumber,
    [Call].Call.Quadrant,
    [Call].Call.CreateDatetime,
    CONVERT(
        datetime,
        [Call].CallUnit.ArriveDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
    ) AS ArriveTime,
    CONVERT(
        datetime,
        [Call].CallUnit.DispatchDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
    ) AS DispatchTime,
    [Call].Call.CommonName,
    [General].CallType.PoliceFlag AS PoliceTypeFlag,
    [General].CallType.FireFlag AS FireTypeFlag,
    CONVERT(
        datetime,
        [Call].Call.ReceivedDatetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
    ) AS ReceivedDatetime,
    [Call].Call.NearestCrossStreet AS ClosestIntersection,
    [General].ValidationSetEntry.EntryID AS CallSourceID,
    [General].ValidationSetEntry.EntryValue AS CallSourceDescription,
    ISNULL(
        PoliceIncident.vsIncidentType,
        [General].CallType.CallTypeID
    ) AS CallTypeID,
    ISNULL(
        val_set_entry_police.EntryValue,
        [General].CallType.Description
    ) AS CallTypeDescription,
    epCIS_Address.AddressID,
    epCIS_Address.HouseNumber AS Number,
    CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetPrefix IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.StreetPrefix)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetPreType IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.StreetPreType)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetName IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.StreetName)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetType IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.StreetType)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetSuffix IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.StreetSuffix)) + ' '
    END AS Street,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.Apt)) AS Apt,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.City)) AS City,
    epCIS_Address.Zip,
    epCIS_Address.Zip4,
    epCIS_Address.Lat,
    epCIS_Address.Lon,
    CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.XStreetPrefix IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.XStreetPrefix)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.XStreetPreType IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.XStreetPreType)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.XStreetName IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.XStreetName)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.StreetType IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.XStreetType)) + ' '
    END + CASE
        WHEN epCIS_Address.XStreetSuffix IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(epCIS_Address.XStreetSuffix)) + ' '
    END AS CrossStreet,
    [Geography].Area.Description AS QuadrantDescription,
    FireIncident.IncidentID AS FireIncidentID,
    FireIncident.IncidentNumber AS FireIncidentNumber,
    PoliceIncident.IncidentID AS PoliceIncidentID,
    PoliceIncident.IncidentNumber AS PoliceIncidentNumber
FROM
    [Call].Call WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [General].ValidationSetEntry WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.vsCallSource = [General].ValidationSetEntry.EntryID
    INNER JOIN [General].CallType WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.CallTypeID = [General].CallType.CallTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN epCIS_Address WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.CurrentAddressID = epCIS_Address.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Call].CallUnit WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.CallID = [Call].CallUnit.CallID
    AND [Call].CallUnit.PrimaryUnitFlag = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Geography].Area WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.Quadrant = [Geography].Area.AreaID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Call].Incident AS PoliceIncident WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.CallID = PoliceIncident.CallID
    AND PoliceIncident.ORIID = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Call].Incident AS FireIncident WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Call].Call.CallID = FireIncident.CallID
    AND FireIncident.ORIID = 9
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [General].ValidationSetEntry AS val_set_entry_police WITH (NOLOCK) ON PoliceIncident.vsIncidentType = val_set_entry_police.EntryID
WHERE
    ([General].CallType.FireFlag = 1)
ORDER BY
    [Call].Call.CallID DESC,
    [Call].Call.CallNumber DESC
```

I want to make a new view that is otherwise identical by adding:

```
,geography::Point(epCIS_Address.Lat, epCIS_Address.Lon, 4326) AS GeomPoint
```

I add it after `PoliceIncident.IncidentNumber AS PoliceIncidentNumber` such that it's the last item in the SQL definition before the `FROM` statement. The error I get is DBMS table not found. But clearly the DBMS table is there, otherwise the view without me adding that geography line would not work.

Comment: Probably better off using Management Studio to construct a view that complex. Note that creating geography on the fly means it can't be indexed, and therefore be very slow.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Pro but make no mention in the question body as to how that is relevant to your question.

Comment: If I were trying to troubleshoot this, I would break it down into smaller pieces in order to understand it. But looking briefly I would suggest casting the lat & lon to decimal or number. Many DBAs create spatial tables and wrongly set fields for lat & lon to be varchar. It's possible that you are trying to create a GeomPoint with varchars and it's not working.